# Magento2 :: Accessing $_FILES using Magento Framework

Tags: magento2, php, upload

I am current working on a file upload functionality in Magento. Everthing is working great.

I am using the `\Magento\Framework\File\Uploader` and files are getting properly uploaded.

The issue I would like to check if the file has been uploaded by the user before I initialize the `Uploader` class.

Currently I am doing is like:

```
if (!empty($_FILES[$field]['name'])) {
    try {
        $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $field]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg','jpeg','gif','png']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $_FILES[$field]['name'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $_FILES[$field]['name']);
        $path = $this->_getUploadPath();
        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$field]['name']);
        $this->_myModel->setData(
            $field,
            "manufacturer/".$uploader->getUploadedFileName()
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    unset($_FILES[$field]);
    //Removing it from data set as no new
    //file was uploaded (fix for edit action)
    $this->_myModel->unsetData($field);
}
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to access `$_FILES` super global using the framework request object by using something like ?

```
$this->getRequest()->getFiles()
```

instead of accessing it directly which I think might be a bad practice to follow.

I tried to search this in the codebase but didn't get anything relevant.

> I am more interested in learning how we may access the $_FILES super global the magento way by using the magento `Request` object not how the proper way of uploading files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also encountered this problem before.
Using global variable `$_FILES` is bad way. Moreover you cannot place module with using of global variables on marketplace. ([SuperglobalSniff in Magento EQP](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/blob/master/MEQP2/Sniffs/Security/SuperglobalSniff.php))

In `RequestInterface` there are no any methods for getting files. But in implementation of `RequestInterface` there is method `getFiles()`, which return requested files data array.

**In sum:**

I use type casting `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` to `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` and fetch files using `getFiles` method.

Comment: Can you please share sample code for this?

Comment: @SaiidatRLTSquare in action `$files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles()`