# File upload in magento 2

Tags: magento2, file-upload

We are using `$_FILES` to check files post data in core php.
Which class can use in Magento 2 to check files post data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will help

```
$files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
```

Here is [Magento2 :: Accessing $_FILES using Magento Framework](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155105/magento2-accessing-files-using-magento-framework?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

```
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

protected $uploaderFactory;


public function __construct(
    ...
    UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory    
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;  
    ....
}

    $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
    $uploader->setFilenamesCaseSensitivity(false);
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $path='YOUR DIRECTORY PATH';
    $result = $uploader->save($path);
```

Where `$fileId` is your name of input file

Comment: Name of input field is groups[vbanktransfer][nineform] in that case what will be the $fileId ??
<input id="vbanktransfer-nineform" name="groups[vbanktransfer][nineform]" data-ui-id="widget-form-renderer-fieldset-element-0-file-groups-vbanktransfer-nineform" value="" type="file">

Comment: It will create the issue (File size is empty)

Comment: can we use this code for multiple file upload fields?