# Magento 2 : How to set $_FILES = $file in Magento 2.3.0 with Magento Coding Standard?

Tags: magento2, php-7, file-upload, coding-standards

I had develop one module and it works currectly 
But When I have check Coding standard using phpcs
it will provide me Error in php coding standard

> --standard=MEQP2

Error is

[image]

i have get result of $_FILES in this format

```
Array
(
    [dynamic_rows_container] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [logo] => BACKGROUNDDEFAULT.jpg
                        )

                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [logo] => image/jpeg
                        )

                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [logo] => D:\xampp72\tmp\php1E43.tmp
                        )

                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [logo] => 0
                        )

                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [logo] => 120785
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and I want in This

```
Array
(
    [logo] => Array
        (
            [name] => BACKGROUNDDEFAULT.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp72\tmp\phpD833.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 120785
        )

)
```

and I have use this code to formate file array
this is my code

```
    foreach ($_FILES['dynamic_rows_container'] as $i => $item) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            $file['logo'][$i] = $value['logo'];
        }
    }
    $_FILES = $file;
```

If any one has solution then Provide me.
thank u in advance.

Comment: @magefms This will give the object manager error

Comment: can you post your code on how you get the array in `$_FILES`

Comment: @magefms i had describe abow

Comment: I mean the whole controller code

Comment: @magefms Pleas check my code which you requested and find any solution

Comment: this one I think will solve the issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155105/magento2-accessing-files-using-magento-framework?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @magefms I have try this for getting file array and it works but i want to assign $_FILES = $files; i want to Edit structure of $_FILES array

Comment: this one I have shared already this can help you https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#109958

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92825/discussion-between-php-developer-and-magefms).

Comment: @magefms the solution is given in this link is not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**it works**
I had Find Solution of it

In Place of

> $_FILES

I had use Dynamic Variable

> ${'_FILES'}

Magento Coding Standard is not Providing any Error or Warning.

Then My Code is

```
foreach (${'_FILES'}['dynamic_rows_container'] as $i => $item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                $file[$fileId][$i] = $value[$fileId];
            }
        }
        ${'_FILES'} = $file;
```

My Functionality is Working Fine and Magento Coding Standard is Not Providing any Type of  Issue.

Please Guide me My way is Right or Not ...............................

Comment: Yes,it is worked great for me

Comment: It only makes sniffer notice disappear ... no good solution. I#d llok for Zend classes that deal with file uploads.

Comment: @sv3n if you have any right way to Update $_FILES structure and value { i will find another way for this issue  }